# What is this strange symbol called :=?

Tags: notation

I want to Google it but I don't even know what to call it.

It looks like some sort of assignment used in computer science or math.

Here it is again

```
:=
```

It is used to describe CS algorithms here:

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~cconway/teaching/cs1007/notes/arrays.pdf

Comment: $A := B$ means (usually, it might have other meanings) that $A$ is _defined_ as $B$.

Comment: It is used when defining something. For instance, $f(x) := x^2$

Comment: Look at the notes I just posted, and it would not make any sense in the context it is used.  Also, does it have a name? For example + is the plus sign, = is the equal sign.

Comment: I don't know if it has a name, but as I recall Pascal used it to mean "is assigned". Probably some other languages, too. I suspect this usage evolved from its use as "is defined as" in math, not the other way around.

Comment: CS and engineering have a tendency to take pure mathematical concepts and blur them to fit reality.

Comment: In this case it seems, this blurred use of the symbol in Pascal, plopped back out on to paper form, where it no longer makes sense.  I would consider this an error by the professor.  He should have just used `=`

Comment: Just saw your update with example. In this case it is used for assignment in pseudocode. "i := i + 1" means "load the location named i with its current value plus one" or, less verbosely, as "i is assigned i + 1". I think this is frequently used in pseudocode, perhaps because of the influence that Pascal once had.

Comment: Well it needs to stop.  `=` makes more sense and is more clear.

Comment: It's easy to figure out what it should mean, but if you are detail oriented like I am, you can't help but wonder why it is there.

Comment: As far as I know (I read this in one of Dijkstra's EWDs), the pure math community stole this notation from Algol.

Comment: The use of ":=" instead of "=" is to distinguish between "is assigned" (a command to be performed) and "is equal to" (which results in a boolean value). Some other languages use "=" vs "==" to make this distinction, but it is probably a useful one. Usage of this notation would NOT be an error by the professor.

Comment: I would disagree, using `=` and `==` are standard ways to differentiate between assignment and equality.  JavaScript, Java and other popular languages use this syntax.  Also math uses `=` to represent assignment.  The professor is using outdated ( or simply less used ) CS language ( not his fault the notes are from 2003 ) syntax when he should be using modern CS language syntax or pure math.

Comment: You can use http://symbolhound.com/ instead of google to search for such symbols.

Comment: The math software Maple uses := as well to assign its variable

Comment: + the language the class is taught in, is Java.  Typical absent minded professor making something simple more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344694/what-does-do.

Answer (score 1):

It is use to define/initialize some variable or function in the programming language. $"="$ is often use to compare stuff to check for instances "if"s like if(x=2) then... while "$:=$" is often used to initialize a parameter, see for example page 19 of your notes, the bubble sort:

The author sets $i$ and $ swap$ to $0$ and then checks some condition with the "if". If he had wanted to check eqality at step $2$, he would ahve used " if $X_i=X_{i+1}$. Then he, if that condition is met, he sets $swap$ to be $1$ by doing $swap:=1$.